# Is there a USB trackpad

Tags: hardware, trackpad

I would like to use a track pad on a Windows machine.

The catch is : I would like to use it through a KVM switch. Thus I cannot pair it with Bluetooth.

I am looking for a USB track pad that I could plug on the switch, but couldn't find one.

Does it exist?

I would prefer an original Apple one, but if it doesn't exist, and the alternatives are good enough, that could do as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use wireless, but it has to be devices that use the 2.4Ghz receivers like the [Logitech Wireless Touchpad](http://radnex.us/logitech-wireless-touchpad).  It uses the "[Unifying Nano Receiver](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/promotions/6072)" that plugs into a USB port.

[image]

I've used many wireless Logitech mice on KVMs (mostly Avocent) and all worked flawlessly.  The touch pad should be no different though I haven't tested it out because I don't own a track pad to test (I don't like them).